# How do I prevent browser caching with Play?

Tags: java, http-headers, playframework, browser-cache

Part of my app provides a file to be downloaded using the `redirect()` method.  I have found that Chrome (and not Firefox or IE, weirdly) is caching this file so that the same version gets downloaded even if it has changed server-side.  I gather that there is a way to tell a browser not to cache a file, e.g. [like this](http://lab.artlung.com/anti-cache/) in the HTML, or by adding something to the HTTP header.  I could probably figure those out in a lower-level web framework, but I don't know how to get at the header in Play!, and the HTML option won't work because it's not an HTML file.

It seems like there's always a clever and simple way to do common tasks in Play!, so is there a clever and simple way to prevent caching in a controller?

Thanks!

### Edit:

Matt points me to the [`http.cacheControl` setting](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/configuration#http), which controls caching for the entire site.  While this would work, I have no problem with most of the site being cached, especially the CSS etc.  If possible I'd like to control caching for one URL at a time (the one pointing to the downloading file in this case).  It's not exactly going to be a high-traffic site, so this is just academic interest talking.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
public static void downloadFile(String url) {
  response.setCaching(false);  // This is the method I'm looking for
  redirect(url);  // Send the response
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Play framework `response` object has a `setHeader` method. You can add the headers you want like this, for example:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tested it, but it looks like the [`http.cacheControl` configuration setting](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/configuration#http) might work.

> #### http.cacheControl
>
> HTTP Response headers control for static files: sets the default max-age in seconds, telling the user’s browser how long it should cache the page. This is only read in `prod` mode, in `dev` mode the cache is disabled. For example, to send `no-cache`:
>
> ```
> http.cacheControl=0
> ```
>
> Default: `3600` – set cache expiry to one hour.

Comment: Nice, I'll try it.  Honestly, I rarely test my answers, so no worries :D. That looks like exactly what I need!

Comment: So that sets the caching parameter for the entire site.  While that would work, I'd like to tell the browser not to cache just one particular URL (in this case, the one pointing to the file).  I'll add that to my question.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually this:

```
response().setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

Comment: In newer editions of Play there is no object called response in play.mvc.Controller it is rather response()

Answer (score 2):

Tommi's answer is ok, but to make sure it works in every browser, use:

```
response().setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, s-maxage=0"); // HTTP 1.1.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this works and why it is the solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

On play currently 2.5.x to 2.8.x
you can set cache life of both assets folder or assets file in configuration.

For folder-

```
play.assets.cache."/public/stylesheets/"="max-age=100"
play.assets.cache."/public/javascripts/"="max-age=200"
```

for specific file -

```
play.assets.cache."/public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css"="max-age=3600"
```

--- documentation
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AssetsOverview